# Mocking extensions from Continuation

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockk

I want to mock `resume` and `resumeWithException` from the standard library `Continuation` class. Both are extension functions.

Here's my JUnit setup function:

```
@MockK
private lateinit var mockContinuation: Continuation<Unit>

@Before
fun setup() {
    MockKAnnotations.init(this)
    mockkStatic("kotlin.coroutines.ContinuationKt")
    every { mockContinuation.resume(any()) } just Runs
    every { mockContinuation.resumeWithException(any()) } just Runs
}
```

However this does not work, throwing the following exception at the mocking of `resumeWithException` function:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Failed matching mocking signature for
SignedCall(retValue=java.lang.Void@5b057c8c, isRetValueMock=false, retType=class java.lang.Void, self=Continuation(mockContinuation#1), method=resumeWith(Any), args=[null], invocationStr=Continuation(mockContinuation#1).resumeWith(null))
left matchers: [any()]

    at io.mockk.impl.recording.SignatureMatcherDetector.detect(SignatureMatcherDetector.kt:99)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState.signMatchers(RecordingState.kt:39)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState.round(RecordingState.kt:31)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.round(CommonCallRecorder.kt:50)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:59)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.EveryBlockEvaluator.every(EveryBlockEvaluator.kt:30)
    at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalEvery(API.kt:92)
    at io.mockk.MockKKt.every(MockK.kt:104)
    at com.blablabla.data.pair.TestConnectSDKDeviceListener.setup(TestConnectSDKDeviceListener.kt:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

And this is the code for `resumeWithException` which is very similar to `resume`:

```
/**
 * Resumes the execution of the corresponding coroutine so that the [exception] is re-thrown right after the
 * last suspension point.
 */
@SinceKotlin("1.3")
@InlineOnly
public inline fun <T> Continuation<T>.resumeWithException(exception: Throwable): Unit =
    resumeWith(Result.failure(exception))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a small investigation. If you are just looking for solution for inline functions and inline classes, scroll to solution section.

**Long explanation**:

These are tricky consequences of modern kotlin features. Let's *decompile* this code to java with help of kotlin plugin. 
This `mockContinuation.resumeWithException(any())` becomes something like this (shortened and beautified version)

```
Matcher matcher = (new ConstantMatcher(true));
Throwable anyThrowable = (Throwable)getCallRecorder().matcher(matcher, Reflection.getOrCreateKotlinClass(Throwable.class));
Object result = kotlin.Result.constructor-impl(ResultKt.createFailure(anyThrowable));
mockContinuation.resumeWith(result);
```

As you can see a few things happened. First, there is no call to `resumeWithException` anymore. Because it is an inline function, it was inlined by the compiler, so now it's a `resumeWith` call. Second, matcher returned by `any()` was wrapped with a mysterious call 
`kotlin.Result.constructor-impl(ResultKt.createFailure(anyThrowable))`, and it's not an argument of a function, called on the mock. That's why mockk can't match the signature and the matcher.
Obviously we can try to fix it by mocking `resumeWith` function itself:

```
every { mockContinuation.resumeWith(any()) } just Runs
```

And it does not work either! Here is the decompiled code:

```
Matcher matcher = (new ConstantMatcher(true));
Object anyValue = getCallRecorder().matcher(matcher, Reflection.getOrCreateKotlinClass(kotlin.Result.class));
mockContinuation.resumeWith(((kotlin.Result)anyValue).unbox-impl());
```

And here is another mysterious call `unbox-impl()`. Let's look at `Result` class definition

```
public inline class Result<out T> @PublishedApi internal constructor(
    @PublishedApi
    internal val value: Any?
)
```

It's an inline class! And `ubox-impl()` is a compiler-generated function like this:

```
public final Object unbox-impl() {
   return this.value;
}
```

Basically, the compiler inlines `Result` object, by replacing it with it's `value`.
So again, instead of calling `resumeWith(any())` in the end we call `resumeWith(any().value)` and mocking library is confused.
So how to mock it? Remember, `mockContinuation.resume(any())` worked for some reason, even though `resume` is just another inline function

```
public inline fun <T> Continuation<T>.resume(value: T): Unit =
    resumeWith(Result.success(value))
```

Decompiling `mockContinuation.resume(any())` gives us

```
Object anyValue = getCallRecorder().matcher(matcher, Reflection.getOrCreateKotlinClass(Unit.class));
Object result = kotlin.Result.constructor-impl(anyValue);
mockContinuation.resumeWith(result);
```

As we can see, it was inlined indeed and `resumeWith` was called with a `result` object, not with `anyValue`, which is our matcher. But, let's take a look at this mysterious `kotlin.Result.constructor-impl`:

```
public static Object constructor-impl(Object value) {
      return value;
}
```

So it actually does not wrap the value, juts return it! That's why it actually works and gives us a solution how to mock `resumeWith`:

```
     every { mockContinuation.resumeWith(Result.success(any())) } just Runs
```

Yes, we are wrapping our matcher into `Result`, which as we saw, gets inlined. But what if we want to distinguish between `Result.success()` and `Result.failure()`?  We still can't mock `mockContinuation.resumeWith(Result.failure(any()))`, because `failure()` call wraps the argument into something else (check the source code or decompiled code above).
So I can think about something like that:

```
     every { mockContinuation.resumeWith(Result.success(any())) } answers {
            val result = arg<Any>(0)
            if (result is Unit) {
                println("success")
            } else {
                println("fail")
            }
        }
```

The `result` value is instance of either our type (`Unit` in this case) or `Result.Failure` type, which is an internal type.

**Solution:**

1. Mocking inline function is generally impossible, because they are inlined at compile time and mocking runs later at runtime. Mock functions, which are called inside inlined function instead.
2. When dealing with inline classes, match inlined value, not the wrapper. So instead of `mock.testFunction(any<InlinedClass>())` use `mock.testFunction(InlinedClass(any<Value>()))`.

[Here](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/152) is a feature request for `mockk` to support inline classes, which is currently in Opened state.

Comment: Thanks, excellent answer, it was a pleasure to read through it!

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks for such details!